# How to preserve session in PGAdmin 4 (web version)

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Is there a way to preserve my session, tabs and queries in PGAdmin 4?

I'm running the web version, and if I refresh the tab or accidentally close the tab, all of my query tools are gone and my work is lost. It would be ideal if PGAdmin 4 would return my environment to the state it was in before the refresh.

Is there a configuration option I can select to allow this to happen?